# Are the various sites going to impose that users give at least a nick name?

Tags: discussion, display-names

There seems to be a lot of users with names like user. Why not impose that they at least give a nick name. Makes it easier to respond to an individual and it would be a minimal effort to do this. Why has this not been done?

**EDIT**

I just think that if people set a username that they are more easier to identify and also that they are more interested to have a "more" real presence - just not a fleeting experience and in the future being a more active member of the community.

Comment: Related: [encourage people to set a username](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142754/would-it-be-better-to-encourage-people-to-set-a-user-name)

Comment: I'm not a massive fan of the word "impose", or "force" for that matter.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - Nor am I - But Humans do have problems identifying people. How much effort is it to pick a name? Makes it easier to identify people. For sake I have given my mutt a name. Should I call him dof197766456456?

Answer (score 3):

If users don't choose a username, they will get an automatically chosen username.
As long as users are notified when a comment @-references their usernames, I don't think it makes any difference if the username was chosen from the user, or it was automatically assigned.

Comment: If it was chosen by the user, it would be easier for us humans to tell them apart than it is to tell user43568 from user48695.

Comment: Still, if the user decided not to choose a username, that choice should be respected. It is rather tedious to tell them apart, but it's not that hard.

Comment: Why? What's the benefit? They can enter their own random username, they can even choose to be user54658632556325 if they like.

Comment: Stack Exchange is written to have less requirements for the users. It doesn't require you to choose a username, as a username is not required to ask questions, in the same way registering an account is not required to ask questions (except on Stack Overflow). What is the benefit? Having more people who use Stack Exchange sites. Is there a difference between a random name chosen from the user, and an automatic random name? The automatic name has probably more chances to be unique.

Comment: There's a big difference; random names chosen by humans are more recognisable by humans. If you really like computer generated uniqueness, why does it have to be numerical? You need roughly 2/3 the number of characters for the same degree of uniqueness, eg bkci stands out far better from bkcl than user45689 stands out from user45698.

Comment: If a person really choose a random name, without any restriction (e.g. avoid using l, which would be misread as 1), then there isn't any practical difference. Then, I would bet it is possible to write code that creates a pseudo-random username, which is unique, and better than a name chosen from a person. (After all, code is still written by people.)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it will more helpful since new nick name(default) will cause same problem . now this is ok just  require little more attention to read .

also this  usename is generated by

```
 user1289000
 ^   ^^^^^^^----------userid
 |___default
```

also when user login first time ... it show notification to change name those who have default just because the want default (IMO)

Comment: You don't _have_ to fill in the user field for them, you can leave it blank and have form validation that makes it required. I think this is what the OP is suggesting.